# Correspondencia de patrones en imágenes deformadas

Tags: python, imagen, opencv, matemáticas

Estoy tratando un problema de *pattern matching*. Estoy analizando una serie de imágenes reales (tomadas por una cámara, con su correspondiente perspectiva cónica). En ellas, hay varios tipos de elementos que sé que siguen un patrón de tipo malla. Os ejemplifico con esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El asunto está en que, precisamente por ser la perspectiva de tipo cónico, las líneas del patrón original están deformadas. Además, solo soy capaz de identificar algunos de los elementos que sé que originalmente existen en la malla completa.

La pregunta es: ¿Cómo enfocaríais la asignación / identificación automática de los elementos que soy capaz de detectar, con los del patrón original (que conozco)?
Con el ejemplo de la imagen, sería cómo identificar los elementos del Stage 3 con los del Stage 1. La respuesta que busco serían los Ids de los elementos de la última imagen que subo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes transformar la perspectiva de `stage3` (con `cv2.wrapPerspective(...)`) para que se vea como la de `stage1` y haces los cálculos ahí, si es necesario aplicas anti-transformada para volver al marco de referencia inicial.

Comment: Hola @AlfredoMaussa . Precisamente quiero hacer la identificación para tener una referencia conocida y poder hacer la homografía al escenario inicial. En conclusión: no conozco los parámetros ni la matriz que me lleva de la Stage 3 a la Stage 1.
Gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: Las líneas hacen parte de la imagen real o son para ilustrar? Los iconos de la imagen deseada no coinciden con el `stage3`.

Comment: Hola de nuevo @AlfredoMaussa . Gracias por tu respuesta, efectivamente estaba mal. Ya la he corregido. Las líneas no hacen parte de la imagen real